# An identity involving a sum of four binomial terms

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, computer-science, computational-mathematics, hypergeometric-function

I need a proof (using a computer is allowed) of the following identity, which involves only binomial sums and products and quotients.

> For $1\leq m\leq k \leq n$: $$A_{k,n,m} + \binom{k}{m}= B_{k,n,m}$$

Where

$$A_{k,n,m} = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=i}^{k-1} \frac{k-j}{k-i} \binom{k-2i}{m-i}\binom{k-i}{i}\binom{j-1}{i-1}\binom{n-k+j-1}{j}$$

and

$$B_{k,n,m} = \sum_{h=0}^{n-k-1} \frac{\binom{n}{k-m}\binom{n}{m}}{\binom{n}{k}}\binom{m-1+h}{h}\binom{k-m+h}{h}\frac{m(h+k-n+1)+n-k}{(h+1)(n-k)}$$

I am aware of the fact that algorithms such as Wilf-Zeilberger's are useful to do such jobs, but I am not being able to access to any computer version of them due to software incompatibility, so a help would be really appreciated (i.e. providing the computational proof and or certificate is perfectly fine).

Comment: For which values of $k, n, m$ do you need to prove it? For example, the definition of $A_{k,n,m}$ requires $k \ge 2$ in order for the second summation to not be empty. Is $A$ undefined when $k < 2$ or is the empty sum treated as $0$?

Comment: You can safely assume that $1\leq m \leq k \leq n$, and for $k=1$ the second sum in $A$ can be treated as a $0$, as you say. I have checked that assuming this, the equality I need to prove still holds. If you need to add any extra hypothesis like $k\geq 3$ to be able to prove it without edge cases, it is welcome as well!

Comment: @LuisFerroni - where does this relation come from and why do you believe it is true?

Comment: I do believe it is true because I do have an extremely long and terrible proof. In just a few words it is just an expression on coefficients of the zeta polynomial of a general uniform matroid, which allows to read more easily some properties of them. I think that the context does not provide much more insight, since these are just pretty ugly polynomials by nature, with explicit combinatorial interpretations in only very few cases.